# Uncaught ReferenceError: Braintree is not defined

Tags: python, django, eclipse, braintree

I am using django framework 1.6.2, eclipse 3.8.1, python 2.7.5

i have followed [This link](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/python/guide/getting_paid) as my sample test program, unfortunately i am getting issue but its working perfect with out using eclipse. please help out, your help is really appreciable

**Client side problem:**

*The code is*

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Braintree Credit Card Transaction Form</h1>
    <div>
      <form action="/create_transaction" method="POST" id="braintree-payment-form">
        <p>
          <label>Card Number</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>CVV</label>
          <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
          <input type="text" size="2" data-encrypted-name="month" /> / <input type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="year" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v1/braintree.js"></script>
    <script>
      var braintree = Braintree.create("YourClientSideEncryptionKey");
      braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*The Bug is*

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Braintree is not defined
```

**Server side problem:**

*The code is*

```
import braintree

braintree.Configuration.configure(braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                              merchant_id="use_your_merchant_id",
                              public_key="use_your_public_key",
                              private_key="use_your_private_key")
```

*Bug is*

```
Undefined variable from import:Sandbox
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it's only happening in Eclipse, not in other web browsers?

Comment: @Drewness: same issue from other web browsers..BTW, i have server side code problem also..

Comment: @user2224250 I work at Braintree. I'm not sure why you're having trouble. The code looks copied directly from our examples, and looks correct. Can you manually reach `https://js.braintreegateway.com/v1/braintree.js` from your web browser where you're getting the ReferenceError? It looks like maybe it's not loading. On the server side, the code is also correct, are you sure you don't have something else named `braintree` that's masking our library? Your best bet is to [send this information to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) so they can help you.

Comment: am having the same error as well. I use PHP.

Answer (score 5):

I used v2 script, but have the same error. The problem was in async loading of scripts.
Your script **braintree.js** is not loaded yet, but next script is already executed and you see error that braintree is not defined.

For solving this problem I used jQuery getScript, and executed second part in callback.

```html
<script>
    $.getScript( "https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js", function() {
        var clientToken = "myTokenClient";
        braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
            container: "payment-form"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing to 
`src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"`
otherwise only Braintree is available in v1 namespace it seems.

Comment: If someone from Braintree sees this, just some notes
- please update documentation in relevant articles,
- and/or provide a explanation between the two.
- please link to js library in [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/client/paypal-and-venmo) and all relevant javascript+stack pages

Answer (score 0):

Moving the code that needed the Braintree script to be properly loaded inside a

```js
$( window ).load(function() {}
```

worked for me.